# How to wrap a 2d vector field around a sphere in Python?

Tags: python, vector, matplotlib, coordinate-systems, coordinate-transformation

I am making a 2d animated plot of a vector field (rectangular latitude/longitude set-up) that will be displayed on a sphere (multiple projectors surrounding the sphere project parts of the animation on each side).

Because of this, I have to make the vectors leave one side of the plot and enter at the correct place on a different side so everything will flow nicely when it is projected. I successfully did this for one of my vector fields, but I realized that I did it by trial and error (tweaking things until it looked right) and that it would only work for that specific vector field.

I have many fields to project, so I was wondering: does there exist a function already that calculates where a field line will "wrap around to" if you are folding your graph into a sphere?

Comment: This seems extremely broad  and asking to find a off site resource so this question seems a bit off topic as it is written, I'd assume you have tried using search engines already to no avail?

Comment: Yes, the only things that come up are creating spheres or converting to spherical coordinates and such. I don't think it's that broad, I was just wondering if anyone with more Python experience than me knew of an existing function that accomplishes this.

Comment: is it so much about transforming the coordinates as mapping out the 2d projections to the 3d shape?  Ny knowledge in this area is limited to idle conversations with a past supervisor of mine so I'm definitely not going to be much help but I wish you luck!